# Error in returning record from function in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, sql-function

```
DECLARE
TYPE type_supplier IS
RECORD(supp_phone supplier.supplier_phone%TYPE,
        supp_status supplier.supplier_status%TYPE);

FUNCTION fn_supplier(supp_name supplier.supplier_name%TYPE)
RETURN type_supplier
IS supp type_supplier;

BEGIN
    select supplier_phone, supplier_status
    into supp.supp_phone, supp.supp_status
    from supplier 
    where supplier_name = supp_name;
    RETURN supp;
END;
```

The question is: Create a function that returns Phone Number and status for inputted supplier name. Supplier table has supplier_id, supplier_name, supplier_address, supplier_email, supplier_phone, supplier_status.
I am getting error in above code as:

```
Error report -
ORA-06550: line 16, column 4:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function pragma procedure
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

I don't know hoe to return multiple values from PL/SQL function. I'm using record type for that but getting the error.

**I am open for any solution, changes or alternative methods..**

Comment: You've got a DECLARE, which starts an anonymous PL/SQL block, then you have a function defined within that anonymous block, and then...there's no BEGIN or END for the anonymous block. So the error message is correct - you've started the definition of an anonymous block but haven't finished it.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of the `TYPE` is not correct.

You can use the `OBJECT` type and use it as follows:

```
create TYPE type_supplier IS
OBJECT(supp_phone supplier.supplier_phone%TYPE,
        supp_status supplier.supplier_status%TYPE);
/

FUNCTION fn_supplier(supp_name supplier.supplier_name%TYPE)
RETURN type_supplier
IS supp type_supplier;

BEGIN
    select supplier_phone, supplier_status
    into supp.supp_phone, supp.supp_status
    from supplier 
    where supplier_name = supp_name;
    RETURN supp;
END;
/
```

Answer (score 0):

In PL/SQL what's commonly done is to return an opened cursor which the caller can then walk through. For example:

```
FUNCTION fn_supplier(supp_name supplier.supplier_name%TYPE)
  RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
  csr  SYS_REFCURSOR
BEGIN
  OPEN csr FOR
    SELECT SUPPLIER_PHONE, SUPPLIER_STATUS
      FROM SUPPLIER
      WHERE SUPPLIER_NAME = pinSupplier_name;

  RETURN csr;
END fn_supplier;
```

Then the caller of the function looks something like:

```
DECLARE
  csrSupplier       SYS_REFCURSOR;
  vSupplier_phone   SUPPLIER.SUPPLIER_PHONE%TYPE;
  vSupplier_status  SUPPLIER.SUPPLIER_STATUS%TYPE;
BEGIN  -- some anonymous
  csrSupplier := fn_supplier('Cthulhu, Inc.');  -- why deal with the lesser evil?

  LOOP
    FETCH csrSupplier INTO vSupplier_phone, vSupplier_status;
    EXIT WHEN cv%NOTFOUND;

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Phone=' || vSupplier_phone ||
                         '  Status=' || vSupplier_status);
  END LOOP;

  CLOSE csrSupplier;
END;
```